# Is there another kind of button in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in html's world. I'm playing this game: https://dragonbound.net 
I'd enter to the "shop". and I'm wondering me about the html code of this. So I went to "inspect element" of the web and I realized that there is no form or href in the buttons.
How these buttons works and Why I can access to the container of the middle that has the items?
For example, this is one of the "buttons"

```css
#buttonShopEyes {
    left: 407px;
    top: 495px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 31px;
    background-position: -72px -204px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonShopEyes" class="opacity_button NoSelect shopButton"><div class="Alt" style="display: none;">G</div></div>
```

When i go to the source, i can see:

```html
<div id="buttonShopEyes" class="opacity_button NoSelect shopButton"><div class="Alt">G</div></div>
```

Comment: You can style anything to look like a button with CSS, or a button to look like anything. Buttons don’t need to be contained in forms, either.

Comment: You can use Javascript onclick event. Like `window.location.href="http://google.com";`

Comment: When you inspect the element you can see what type of element the 'button' is. What does it show?

Comment: This is not a HTML `<button>`. It's a `<div>` element made to look like a physical button but it is not a HTML `<button>`. A `<div>` is a generic container. A `<button>` is a button.

Comment: I know that this is no a <button>, I want to know how this works like a button, besides to looks to like a button

Answer (score 0):

Many HTML elements can behavior like buttons. For instance: a, divs, spans, p, etc. However, if you want to develop a consistent code, you should pay attention to the semantic. If you need a button, create a button element. You can change all style properties for the button if you want. If you create a `<a href="someplace">Some place</a>` element, you should redirect the user to another place, (i.e. another page, or another anchor, in the same page). Avoid using `<a href="javascript:void(null)">` or `<a href="#">`, instead, use a button in that cases.

HTML is free to use of many ways, you should be aware of the best practices.